# ASP.MET MVC Multiple Model in One View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use multiple model in one view, I red some article to use complex Model, or Partial View, or Viewbag and other,but couldn't find  normal answer.

I want to display data from different models.
Here is my Models

```
 public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

 public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherLname { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }


}
 public class ClassOut
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClassOutName { get; set; }
}



 public class SchoolDbContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClassOut> ClassOuts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine all your models in one common view model and use it in your view.

```
public class ViewModelName 
{
    public Department Department {get; set;}
    public Teacher Teacher {get; set;}
    public ClassOut ClassOut {get; set;}
}
```

Use this model for your view:

```
    @model ViewModelName
    ......
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Teacher.TeacherName )
    .....
```

And in your post action method

```
public ActionResult MethodName(ViewModelName viewModel)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: I cannot get it , please help what should i write in my controller? I only want to display departments and teachers in my view

Comment: In order to display them, first you need to get them from your database and asign their values to your view model, then you can show the desired result in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a Class ( for example Manager) where you add a variable for Department, ClassOut, ClassOutName and then you pass the Class Manager to the view and then you can access easily

```
public class Manager
{
  public Department dept;
  public ClassOut cl;
  public ClassOutName clname;
}
```